# Extract only numbers using regexp

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am new to tableau, and am trying to write a regular expression which returns a number that is between parentheses. The input field has several lines. The word "Resolution" is a keyword.

Example:

```
1. text "Resolution(05:10): text"
2. text "Resolution(15:03): text"
```

Desired result:

```
01. 05:10
02. 15:03
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH`:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([column], '\((\d{2}:\d{2})\)', 1)
```

The `\((\d{2}:\d{2})\)` matches a `(`, then captures into Group 1 two digits, `:`, and 2 more digits, then matches a `)`. The `1` in the function is the ID of the first capturing group in the pattern.

See [this Tableau blog](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/6/become-regular-regular-expressions-39802) showing how to use regular expressions with Tableau.